# How to add a unique HTML ID attribute to an ngx-datatable-column

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

Is there a way to add a unique HTML ID attribute to an ngx-datatable-column? I've tried this, but can't seem to get it to work. For example:

```
<ngx-datatable-column id="row.id" prop="dateDue" name="Date Due">
    <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        {{ row.id }}
    </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
// the row id renders as expected for testing purposes, however I'm wanting to add a unique ID to the ngx-datatable-column with the HTML ID set to the unique ID being passed
```

Comment: hey, can you provide us a stackblitz with an example of what you're trying to do ? :)

Comment: Hey Alan, I'm working on a enterprise project, so I can't w/out creating a mock w/ dummy data. Long story short, I'm just wanting to add a unique identifier to each column, which is a requirement from QA to test the code base. You'd figure this would be quite easy, but when using Google's Developer Tools to look at the element there is not an HTML ID attribute. Even if I were to not dynamically add the ID, but just add a static ID, the attribute is not there.

Comment: I don't ask you to give us the data from your enterprise project, but make a simple reproductible case with the library, I'm not used to ngx-datatable but I can try to help you find a solution with a little example :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `id="row.id"` to `id="{{row.id}}"` but it'll be in column not in a row.